# I have filled a pending patent, can I still publish my code as an open source?

Tags: open-source-definition, patents

I have filled a pending patent for my project in USPTO, can I still publish the source code (project) as an open source?
What about that if I had a complete patent for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) it appears to be asking for legal advice, (b) much of the needed information is missing (country of filing, for example), (c) code itself is not generally patentable only the algorithms - and then only in countries which recognize software patents.

Comment: @kdopen I did edit the question my friend :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the "legal advice" concern still stands

Comment: And, from past experience, it can take many, **many** years for a patent application to be finally granted. I've just had some land which I filed back in the early noughties.

Comment: Hmmm... You've got a really good question here that concerns patents. I'm not entirely sure how this would play out, it looks like a good on-topic question here. If the community deems the open source part coincidental (and that would make this question almost off-topic), this question may be a good question at Ask Patents. Don't cross post, but in the mean time, trying making your question more specific :)

Comment: Reading the reasoning behind the patent license of GPLv3 could provide some insight.

Comment: Too broad without specifying a license.

Comment: Maybe too broad, but instead of asking for a specific license, I'd like to know what the OP is actually asking for. The reason for the question is most likely some sort of fear or doubt, and knowing that is IMO necessary to answer it.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: Given the [other recent question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/how-can-i-get-benefits-priority-out-of-my-open-source-code) by OP, it seems likely that OP's patent-applied idea is something they want to both share publicly *and* operate for profit. So it seems less "fear and doubt" and more "fame and fortune".

Comment: Then the doubt could be something like "Could my patent be declared invalid if I distribute an open source project based on it?". This would be a question that we couldn't answer here, but at least it would make this obvious. The opposite would be "Does anything prevent me from releasing an open source project if I have a patent on something it is based on?".